# Property destination is unknown for <class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.load.LoadJobConfig'> - BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to insert data into a Big Query table, but I get the following error:

```python
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\me\gsc.py", line 77, in <module>
        y = get_sc_df(p,"2020-03-02","2020-03-02",x)
      File "C:\Users\me\gsc.py", line 62, in get_sc_df
        job_config.destination = table_ref
      File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\google\cloud\bigquery\job\base.py", line 713, in __setattr__
        raise AttributeError(
    AttributeError: Property destination is unknown for <class 'google.cloud.bigquery.job.load.LoadJobConfig'>.
```

This is the code around the mentioned lines:

```python
        # establish a BigQuery client
        client = bigquery.Client.from_service_account_json(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
        dataset_id = BQ_DATASET_NAME
        table_name = BQ_TABLE_NAME
        # create a job config
        job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
        # Set the destination table
        table_ref = client.dataset(dataset_id).table(table_name)
        job_config.destination = table_ref
        job_config.write_disposition = 'WRITE_APPEND'

        load_job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(result, table_ref, job_config=job_config)
        load_job.result()
```

I have tried using the Big Query table ID and basic name, but neither seems to work.

I'm wondering if it's a setting I need to change in the cloud interface, but I'm at a loss to be honest.

Does anyone know what could be causing the above error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove

> job_config.destination = table_ref

It is similar to `load_table_from_uri`. Look at the examples here: https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/usage/tables.html